# Entering the main menu in the Connect IQ Simulator

Tags: garmin, connectiq

I am unsuccessful entering he Main Menu in the Connect IQ Fenix3 Simulator.
I tried holding the "Up" key as in the watch, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Pressinng 'M' on the keyboard allows me to enter the Fenix 6s emulator menu.

Answer (score 2):

The simulator is for running Connect IQ apps (and widgets, data fields and watch faces) only. No other watch functionality (such as the built-in widgets or settings menu) are available. Instead, most of the configuration done via the settings menu is done using the "Settings" menu option within the simulator, where you can set things like units, language and 12/24 hour time.

That said, @Eugène is not correct about button presses. Watch events, such as button presses, press and hold or touch screen swipes (depending on the device) are all supported within the simulator, allowing you to simulate functionality as if it was running on a actual device.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few months since I used this environment, but as far as I can remember the "watch simulators" do not support button press.
I used the Round Watch Simulator, as that has buttons on the Simulator that fires the actions as required.

After compile and deploy though it works 100%.

Would be nice if all of them had that.

Comment: I'm using the regular simulator that comes with the SDK, It shows the picture of the Fenix 3 and all the buttons work except holding the "up" button in order to access the settings.

Comment: Ah really nice!, See just now there is newer SDK's :) Will download and and get coding again, been too long.

Answer (score 1):

Use your computer keyboard:

- Enter = SELECT/ENTER
- Up Arrow = UP
- Down Arrow = DOWN
- ESC = BACK
- m   = MENU